# Is there a simple way to enforce a minimum in input when the type is number in the return statement of a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know that something like below may work, but I feel that it is too complex.

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput" min="5" />
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (input.value < 5) {
    input.setCustomValidity("Value must be at least 5");
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The form submit handler will do that by default (hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when focussed on the input or add a `<button>`), is there a reason you need it interactively?

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" min="5" value="3"/>
</form>
```

Edit: For changing the value interactively:

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.value = Math.max(this.value, 5);
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput" min="5" />
```

Comment: I want that any number smaller than 5 can not be input in the box.

Comment: @Steven I added a handler for that

Comment: Seems that no simple way to do it.